# Oracle SQL get lowest balance for each Account type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to list the last and first names of a customer and account type/description but only of those that have the lowest balance for each account type.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Select Surname || ', ' || First_name AS "Name", account_description
from WGB_CUSTOMER join WGB_ACCOUNT using (Customer_number) join              
WGB_ACCOUNT_TYPE using (Account_type)
where salary <ANY
(select MIN(Balance), account_type
 from wgb_account
Group by account_type);
```

This is an error and says too many values. The last part of the code (starting from select MIN(Balance) by itself does only show the account types with the lowest balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `rank() over (partition by`

```
Select 
    Name, 
    account_description
from (
    select Surname || ', ' || First_name AS Name
    account_description
    rank() over (partition by Account_type order by Balance) rnk
    from WGB_CUSTOMER
) x
where rnk = 1;
```

using `join`

```
Select 
    t.Surname || ', ' || t.First_name AS Name, 
    t.account_description
from wgb_account t  
join (
    select MIN(Balance) min_bal, account_type
    from wgb_account
    Group by account_type
) x
on x.min_bal = t.Balance
and x.account_type = t.account_type
```